# Updating ListView after animation

Tags: android-listview, android-animation, android-adapter

My app has a sliding drawer for notifications.  I've managed to get it to function like the android notifications including the "clear all" button.

When the clear all button is clicked my database is cleared, my list adapter is refreshed, and my list adapter gets set to the list.  The view updates and the list is cleared.

When I added slide-out animation (just like jelly bean) I got a NullPointerException. The issue crops up when my adapter is set.  If I comment out setting the adapter the animation runs without a problem.

```
            // Animation
        int count = drawer_list.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View view = drawer_list.getChildAt(i);
            if (view != null) {
                // create an Animation for each item
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                animation.setDuration(300);

                // ensure animation final state is "persistent"
                animation.setFillAfter(true);

                // calculate offset (bottom ones first, like in notification panel)
                animation.setStartOffset(300 * (count - 1 - i));

                // animation listener to execute action code
                if (i == 0) {
                    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            // NOT USED

                        }

                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            // NOT USED

                        }

                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                            // Clear table
                            notifications.flushNotificationTempTable_ActiveOnly();
                            // Update list adapter
                            refreshNotifications();
                            // Close drawer
                            notification_drawer.close();
                        }
                    });
                }

                view.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
```

The trouble spot is in the refreshNotifications() method when the line `drawer_list.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);` executes.  I use this method and adapter all throughout my app and, as I said above, it works flawlessly without the animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by eliminating the animation listener and adding a delayed runnable after it that ran my post animation code.

I was unable to find a way to set a new adapter (required because i used a custom adapter) inside the animation listener.  If anyone knows how to do this I would like to know.